# Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

Alguém sabe se é possível retirar as marcações automáticas do google de dentro do mapa?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses marcadores já carregam junto com o mapa, gostaria de saber se é possível retirar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Isso é publicidade do Google, o preço a pagar por ser gratuito... se quiseres tirar tens de encontrar um serviço pago acho eu.

Comment: Se você utilizar o google maps api e gerar seu próprio map com sua Key... nao vai ter isso aí.

Answer (score 1):

Você se refere aos estabelecimentos, pontos de onibus e tudo mais que aparece?
Tem como retirar.

```
var mapOptions = {                        
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,                        
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                        mapOptions);

var noPoi = [
                    {
                        featureType: "all",
                        stylers: [
                            {visibility: "off"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        featureType: "road",
                        stylers: [
                            {visibility: "on"}
                        ]
                    }
                ];
                map.setOptions({styles: noPoi});
```

Comment: André isso mesmo que eu queria, me ajudou 100% mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**Eu removi assim:**

```
var noPoi = [
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
            ]   
          }
        ];
        map.setOptions({styles: noPoi});
```